# Karate-Cucumber Report - No report file was added

Tags: cucumber, karate

I had to run maven clean command by mistake and the target report folder go cleansed. Now, If I build and run my feature file i get below error. How can I resolve this?

BTW, I am using karate version 0.9.0 (Even though it might not depend)

And also, How can I clean the report folder if its causing below issues?

```html
19:07:59.921 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate.Runner - Karate version: 0.9.0
Karate version: 0.9.0
======================================================
elapsed:   0.01 | threads:    5 | thread time: 0.00 
features:     0 | ignored:    0 | efficiency: 0.00
scenarios:    0 | passed:     0 | failed: 0
======================================================

Dec 13, 2018 7:08:00 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder generateErrorPage
INFO: Unexpected error
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added!
 at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:58)
 at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:88)
 at PP1.RunnerClasses.Validationrunner.generateReport(Validationrunner.java:45)
 at PP1.RunnerClasses.Validationrunner.testParallel(Validationrunner.java:35)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

19:08:00.696 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - CommonsLogLogChute name is 'org.apache.velocity'
19:08:00.696 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Initializing Velocity, Calling init()...
19:08:00.697 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Starting Apache Velocity v1.7 (compiled: 2010-11-19 12:14:37)
19:08:00.697 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Default Properties File: org\apache\velocity\runtime\defaults\velocity.properties
19:08:00.697 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Trying to use logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute
19:08:00.697 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Target log system for org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute is not available (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log/format/Formatter).  Falling back to next log system...
19:08:00.697 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Trying to use logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute
19:08:00.699 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Target log system for org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute is not available (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout).  Falling back to next log system...
19:08:00.700 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Trying to use logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute
19:08:00.700 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Using logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute
19:08:00.709 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceLoader instantiated: org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:00.735 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceCache: initialized (class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceCacheImpl) with class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap cache map.
19:08:00.738 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Stop
19:08:00.740 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Define
19:08:00.742 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Break
19:08:00.744 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Evaluate
19:08:00.746 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Literal
19:08:00.749 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Macro
19:08:00.753 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Parse
19:08:00.757 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Include
19:08:00.761 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach
19:08:00.874 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Created '20' parsers.
19:08:00.889 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : "velocimacro.library" is not set.  Trying default library: VM_global_library.vm
19:08:00.890 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Could not load resource 'VM_global_library.vm' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader: ClasspathResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource VM_global_library.vm
19:08:00.890 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : Default library not found.
19:08:00.890 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : allowInline = true : VMs can be defined inline in templates
19:08:00.890 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : allowInlineToOverride = false : VMs defined inline may NOT replace previous VM definitions
19:08:00.890 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : allowInlineLocal = false : VMs defined inline will be global in scope if allowed.
19:08:00.890 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : autoload off : VM system will not automatically reload global library macros
19:08:01.243 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found templates/generators/errorpage.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.258 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/headers.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.259 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/head.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.265 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM stringArray: source=/templates/macros/array.js.vm
19:08:01.265 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM numberArray: source=/templates/macros/array.js.vm
19:08:01.265 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/array.js.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.269 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeBuildInfo: source=/templates/macros/page/buildinfo.vm
19:08:01.270 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/page/buildinfo.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeClassifications: source=/templates/macros/page/classifications.vm
19:08:01.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/page/classifications.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.280 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeLead: source=/templates/macros/page/lead.vm
19:08:01.280 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/page/lead.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.286 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeNavigation: source=/templates/macros/page/navigation.vm
19:08:01.286 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/page/navigation.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.291 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeReportInfo: source=/templates/macros/page/reportInfo.vm
19:08:01.292 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/page/reportInfo.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.295 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeTitle: source=/templates/macros/page/title.vm
19:08:01.295 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/page/title.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.304 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeExpandingButtons: source=/templates/macros/report/expandAllButtons.vm
19:08:01.304 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/report/expandAllButtons.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.312 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeReportTable: source=/templates/macros/report/reportTable.vm
19:08:01.313 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/report/reportTable.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.318 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeReportHeader: source=/templates/macros/report/reportHeader.vm
19:08:01.318 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/report/reportHeader.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.327 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeStatsTable: source=/templates/macros/report/statsTable.vm
19:08:01.327 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/report/statsTable.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.330 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeBrief: source=/templates/macros/json/brief.vm
19:08:01.330 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/brief.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.335 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeDocString: source=/templates/macros/json/docstring.vm
19:08:01.337 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/docstring.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.342 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeDuration: source=/templates/macros/json/duration.vm
19:08:01.342 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/duration.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.347 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeElement: source=/templates/macros/json/element.vm
19:08:01.347 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/element.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.385 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeEmbeddings: source=/templates/macros/json/embeddings.vm
19:08:01.386 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeHtmlEmbedding: source=/templates/macros/json/embeddings.vm
19:08:01.387 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeImageEmbedding: source=/templates/macros/json/embeddings.vm
19:08:01.388 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeImageReferenceEmbedding: source=/templates/macros/json/embeddings.vm
19:08:01.388 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeTextEmbedding: source=/templates/macros/json/embeddings.vm
19:08:01.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeUnknownEmbedding: source=/templates/macros/json/embeddings.vm
19:08:01.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/embeddings.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.392 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeHooks: source=/templates/macros/json/hooks.vm
19:08:01.392 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/hooks.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.397 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeOutput: source=/templates/macros/json/output.vm
19:08:01.397 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/output.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.401 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeMessage: source=/templates/macros/json/message.vm
19:08:01.401 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/message.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeSteps: source=/templates/macros/json/steps.vm
19:08:01.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/steps.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.409 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeStepName: source=/templates/macros/json/stepName.vm
19:08:01.409 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/stepName.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.412 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Velocimacro : added VM includeTags: source=/templates/macros/json/tags.vm
19:08:01.413 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/macros/json/tags.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
19:08:01.440 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - VM #includeNavigation: too few arguments to macro. Wanted 1 got 0
19:08:01.442 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Left side ($active_tab) of '==' operation has null value. If it is a reference, it may not be in the context or its toString() returned null. /templates/macros/page/navigation.vm[line 14, column 51]
19:08:01.442 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Left side ($active_tab) of '==' operation has null value. If it is a reference, it may not be in the context or its toString() returned null. /templates/macros/page/navigation.vm[line 15, column 51]
19:08:01.442 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Left side ($active_tab) of '==' operation has null value. If it is a reference, it may not be in the context or its toString() returned null. /templates/macros/page/navigation.vm[line 16, column 51]
19:08:01.443 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Left side ($active_tab) of '==' operation has null value. If it is a reference, it may not be in the context or its toString() returned null. /templates/macros/page/navigation.vm[line 20, column 51]
19:08:01.465 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Null reference [template 'templates/generators/errorpage.vm', line 23, column 85] : $build_number cannot be resolved.
19:08:01.465 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - Null reference [template 'templates/generators/errorpage.vm', line 23, column 85] : $build_number cannot be resolved.
19:08:01.480 [main] DEBUG org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : found /templates/footer.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved myself; Used *karate-junit4* instead of *karate-junit5* which is was using earlier in my .pom file.

But, I still don't understand why this error is caused if i used junit5!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will work for the karate 1.0.1 version

```
          /**
           * Use this method if you want to execute entire feature files available in any folder.
           */
          @Test
          public void runMultipleFeatureFiles() {
            System.setProperty("karate.env", "qa");
            Results results = Runner.builder().outputCucumberJson(true)
                .path("classpath:features/apitests/testFeatures").tags("~@Ignore").parallel(2);
            Assertions.assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount());
            generateReport(results.getReportDir());
          
    
    }
    
      /**
       * Generate test case execution report post-execution.
       *
       * @param karateOutputPath - directory where you want to keep a report of test case executions.
       */
      public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles =
            FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<String>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "ReqRes.in SampleAPI Testing");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
  }
```

In Pom.xml add this maven dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
     <version>5.3.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure why this didn't get any more votes or comments. This is what worked for me. Especially the part on `outputCucumberJson(true)`. Vote up @Sudheer Singh

Answer (score 2):

//My runner file

```
@Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:conduitApp")
        .outputCucumberJson(true)
        .tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
        
    }
```

Note that outputCucumberJson(true) is called on the Runner “builder” to make it work.